# Duplicate entries on UPDATE SET field=CONCAT("string", field)

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm trying to update emails in my users table with some prefix. Problem is, it gives me "duplicate entry prefixuseremail@mail.com for key 'IDX_EMAIL'" error for uniqe index in this field, when I am trying to execute this query:

```
UPDATE user SET email=CONCAT("prefix", email)
```

My question is: if there aren't duplicate entries in this field in the first place, how could they be created with aforementioned query if it just adds a prefix to a unique string?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? How does its CONCAT() handle null values?

Comment: (1) Do not forget the WHERE user selection. (2) If sufficiently often the UPDATE would be executed, the field overflows, and might be truncated to "prefixprefixprefi"?

Comment: I use HeidiSql to connect to a remote MariaDB database. Not sure how CONCAT handles null values, but I doubt it has any relevancy, since there are no entries with NULL value in email field

Comment: Are you sure there are no duplicates? Do `select email from user group by email having count(*) > 1` and see if any emails are returned.

Comment: Yeah, Im positive there are no duplicates. Double-checked with your query,  and it returned no results. Is it even possible to have duplicates in the field with unique constraint?

Comment: Disable/delete the index, run the update and re-enable it. Does it work out? If this is a prod system and you dont want to mess with anything like that, create a new table of the same schema as the existing one and insert all the data to it, then update the new table

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in unique index length, which was set to 30. There are plenty of duplicate emails when it tries to strip values of email field to 30 characters.